# Cloning Page Types using REST API

Tags: kentico

Is there a way to clone or convert a non-content type page type into content only page type using kentico REST API. '

There is nothing mentioned in the documentation about handling page types (https://docs.kentico.com/k10/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/configuring-the-rest-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know REST API does not provide you with a possibility to clone pages or object. It provides CRUD operations plus extra methods for workflow and attachments.

Also I don't think Kentico will allow you to convert content only page type to regular one or vice versa through Kentico admin or API, so definitely REST service does not provide that function to you.